# Plotting the space-coordinate path of a projectile

Tags: plotting

```
h = .01; g = 9.8; x[0] = 0; y[0] = 0; V[0] = 40
Vy[0] = 40 Sin[40 °]
Vy[n_] := Vy[n - 1] - g*h
Vx[n_] := 40 Cos[40 °]
x[n_] := x[n - 1] + 40 Cos[40 °]*h
y[n_] := y[n - 1] + Vy[n - 1]*h
t == (V[0]*2*Sin[40 °])/g
R == (V[0]^2*Sin[2*40 °])/g
Ymax == Sin[40 °]^2*V[0]^2/(2 g)
ParametricPlot[{y[n], x[n]}, {n, 0, 5}]
```

I'm trying to plot `y[n]` vs `x[n]` but keep getting an error message and *Mathematica* keeps crashing. I did use `ParametricPlot`, but get a "Recursion depth" error message. I am also unsure of what my start and end points for n should be.

Comment: What is the error message and from what expression are you getting it? Add the answers to these questions to your question; don't answer me by posting a comment.

Comment: Y[0] calls y[-1] which is undefined. It also calls Vy[0], which calls Vy[-1] which is also undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions x and y appear to be only defined on integers, so you can only plot them over the integers. One way is to use `ListPlot`.

```
h = .01; g = 9.8; x[0] = 0; y[0] = 0; V[0] = 40;
Vy[0] = 40 Sin[40 \[Degree]];
Vy[n_] := Vy[n - 1] - g*h;
Vx[n_] := 40 Cos[40 \[Degree]];
x[n_] := x[n - 1] + 40 Cos[40 \[Degree]]*h;
y[n_] := y[n - 1] + Vy[n - 1]*h;
ListPlot@Table[{x[s], y[s]}, {s, 1, 10, 1}]
```